# Resubmitting a Form That Has jQuery Submit Function and Return False

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, return

I am using jquery to call an action when a form is submitted. I am also using return false; to prevent the page from being refreshed. However, when I try to resubmit the form - it doesn't work, but I need it to (e.g. new data entered in the field).

Currently, I am using this structured:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="myform">
<input type="text" name="test" value="test">
</form>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myform').submit(function(){
    // Some action here
    return false;
    });
    });
```

EDIT: I am not looking to submit the form. I just want it to fire a jQuery function every time the submit button is pressed. With the current example the action only works once (the first time the submit button is pressed). It seems like the preventing stops the functionality of the submit button completely.

EDIT2: Okay, let me clarify. I don't have a submit button. I only have a text input and whenever someone fills it and presses the Enter key (e.g. the form's submit is fired) I want to get this input value via jQuery and do something. The issue is that now I can only do this once (pressing enter the second time with new value in the text input does nothing). I am guessing the return false is causing this.

Comment: Of course it won't work. You prevented the form from submitting with `return false`.

Comment: If you need the form to submit at some point then make the return value contingent upon some condition.

Answer (score 3):

Remove return false then it works. You are preventing to submit the form.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("myButton").click(function() {
        $('#myform').submit(function() {
            // Some action here
            //return false;
        });
    });
});​
```

Comment: Alright, but wouldn't this submit the form when I first click on the submit button? I want it to only run a jQuery function, but run it every time the submit button is clicked (without actually submitting the form data via POST or GET and going to another URL)

Comment: You can put condition there when the form should submit.
eg: `if(condition) { return true } else { return false }`

Comment: I have edited my question with more information on this issue. I have a form with only one input text (no submit button). I capture the submit request after filling the field and pressing Enter and process the data. However, this only works once due to the return false in the jQuery (I guess this is the issue, it may be something else).